# Why file upload doesn't work in formsubmit.co when using AJAX form method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, form-submit

I have a static website built with Gatsby and there is a contact form including file upload. Cause I don't want to setup a back-end, I choose [FormSubmit.co](https://formsubmit.co/) service to handle sending email on every form submissions. 
It worked fine uploading file and I received the file in my email just when I used the **method: adding the endpoint to the form action** `action="https://formsubmit.co/my@email.com"`, As described in [DOCS](https://formsubmit.co/documentation) .  
But that method redirects page to another; so because I don't want the page to be redirected and wanna show my own message, I decided to use the [AJAX method](https://formsubmit.co/ajax-documentation).
This is my code getting Name and File from user, and the handleSubmit function:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const MyForm = () => {
 const form = useRef(null);

 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form.current);

    fetch('https://formsubmit.co/ajax/my@email.com', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

 return (
  <form ref={form} method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input id="name" name="Name" />
    <input type="file" id="file" name="File" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
 );
};
```

**The problem** is while using AJAX form, the file wouldn't upload and I don't receive it in my email. But there is no error msg and even I think the file has been sent! according to the POST request at network:

[image: File data in nework POST request]
I've also tried Axios library, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @AlokJain, no I just kept using the first method described in my question. I also sent an email to the support but they didn't respond.

Comment: You'd need to look at what the server is responding to the request with as the next step in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` instead of `encType`.
you can check out this link for more info on how to use formsubmit.co https://formsubmit.co/documentation